# How to keep remain void islands in raster while mosaic?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, raster-calculator

I have raster images of DEM files

[image]

After running Mosaic To New Raster, I am getting images were all void spaces are getting filled(Highlighted with red lines in above image)

[image]

Below is the setting I have used

[image]

As a result, I am looking for a mosaic raster as it is. 
I am using Arcgis Desktop 10.7.1

Comment: Are the rasters that you are mosaicking overlapping? If so then one would expect void/no data spaces of one raster to fill with values from the underlying raster.

Comment: No, There is no overlapping in rasters.

Comment: In your mosaic raster when you click in those areas with the info tool what value is it returning? They may actually be NODATA but you are symbolising no data as black by default?